# This declaration has no storage class or type specifier in C++

Tags: c++

I have multiple classes in my program.

A) When I create an object of a class in another class I am getting no error but when I use the object to call a function I get the above error.

B)Also if I create an object of another class and call a function using that  in the constructor of my class then I get no error like this.

C) Cout function does not work in the body of the class except when I put it any function

D) The main class is able to do all of these and I am not getting any error.

It would be great to hear back soon. Thank you in advance.

Following is the code : These are two classes in my cpp. I am facing no problems except using object after creating it. the code is too huge too be posted. Everything can be done in main but not in other classes why?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib> 
 #include <vector>
 #include <map>
 using namespace std;
 class Message
 {
    public:
    void check(string side)
   {
       if(side!="B"&&side!="S")
       {
           cout<<"Side should be either Buy (B) or Sell (S)"<<endl;;
       }
   }


};

class Orderbook
{
    public:
      string side;
      Orderbook()      //No Error if I define inside constructor
      Message m;       //No Error while declaring
      m.check(side);   //Error when I write m. or m->
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you're putting *expressions* where only *declarations* can appear. It would be so much easier to help if you showed us your code...

Comment: @jrok Seems you can help me now

Comment: Please edit the code indenting style for more consistency.  Is the `using namespace std;` somewhere above?  Are the two classes inside a header or cpp? What header files are being included?

Comment: This code is wrong in so many ways I'd just tell you to learn more about programming in C++ before trying to achieve something like that. I've properly indented your code.

Comment: I have edited and provided additional info. Can you tell me some of the so many mistakes you see ?

Comment: "Everything can be done in main but not in other classes why?" / "The main class" - are you referring to the main *function*? A function is not a class.

Comment: ya Sorry I mean main function

Comment: Is your compiler giving you errors in at least two separate lines?  What compiler, compiler version, and operating system are being used here?

Comment: You should be getting an error on `Orderbook()` as you've missed a semi-colon. Please post real code (i.e. the actual code you're using). And full error messages. However, your main mistake is here: `m.check(side);` - you can't call a function inside a class definition. It needs to be in a member function / constructor / destructor.

Comment: Also, as a matter of style - there's no point in creating a class just to contain a single static function. This isn't Java, where everything is in a class. Have a free function and place it inside a namespace instead. Your current code is confusing - the line `m.check(side);` suggests to the reader that the `m` object is going to be checked, but that isn't the case.

Comment: You probably want to put it in the constructor: `Orderbook() {m.check_side();}`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a mistake:

```
m.check(side);
```

That code has to go inside a function.
Your class definition can only contain declarations and functions.

Classes don't "run", they provide a blueprint for how to make an object.

The line `Message m;` means that  an `Orderbook` will contain `Message` called `m`, if you later create an `Orderbook`.

Comment: `s/Classes don't "run"/Class declarations don't "run"/`

Comment: Thank you so much . I was calling a function in the class defination. It works fine inside a function .

Comment: @Jain neither classes, class declarations, nor class definitions run . Although I guess this all depends on your definition of "run"

Answer (score 9):

Calling m.check(side), meaning you are running actual code, but you can't run code outside main() - you can only define variables.

In C++, code can only appear inside function bodies or in variable initializes, unless it's a function that initializes a static variable.

Comment: You can run code outside main just fine if it's a function that initializes a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an object of a class in another Class,that's possible but you cant initialize that object. For that  you need to do something like this :-->
(inside main)

```
Orderbook o1;
o1.m.check(side)
```

but that would be unnecessary. Keeping things short :-

***You can't call functions inside a Class***

Answer (score 0):

jrok nailed it with the first comment.
I just provided the corrected code as my answer.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <string>
  #include <cstdlib> 
  #include <vector>
  #include <map>
  using namespace std;

  class Message {
  public:
    void check(string side)
      {
      if (side != "B" && side != "S") {
        cout << "Side should be either Buy (B) or Sell (S)" << endl;;
        }
      }
    };

  class Orderbook {
  public:
    string side;
    Orderbook () { side = ""; }
    void Check () {
      Message m;
      m.check (side);   //NO ERROR: Error when I write m. or m->
      };
    };

  int main()
    {
    Orderbook ob;
    ob.Check ();
    return 0;
    }
```