# C++ | This declaration has no storage class or type specifier VS Code 1.34.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have this strange problem and I do not know why this happens. Since yesterday I get this problem message `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier` for my code in VS Code (Version 1.34.0, OS: Windows 10, Compiler: MinGW). Yesterday I was trying to learn how to write with `fstream` (I don't know if this is relevant I thought maybe that could be the source of the problem because of some strange behavior of fstream.). The code compiles and I can run the exe file without any problems. This problem message (the problem message is pointing to the last line) persists even if I remove the whole body of the main function.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    int sum{0};
    std::cout << "Why?\n";
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This is a screenshot with an empty body of the main function.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This declaration has no storage class or type specifier in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899466/this-declaration-has-no-storage-class-or-type-specifier-in-c)

Comment: What about that remark on `fstream`? What does it have to do with your code?

Comment: aside from `int main(void)` this code is valid and should compile file

Comment: @VTT: I removed the void in the main function and it still gives me the problem message ... which was not there previously.

Comment: What line causes the warning?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this problem message is a bug in VS Code. Restarting VS Code didn't help. But restarting Windows solved the issue.